# Change title name in Twitter API using Android?

Tags: android, twitter

When you use Twitter API and develop your first simple Twitter client, and post a comment to Twitter - it says "from API". Using the Twitter web it says "from the web". Using Siesmic it says "from Seesmic".

How do you the set the application name/title so it shows up like "from myApp" using Android?

Thanx for listening! Answers will be rewarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Twitter REST change "from API" to something meaningful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112245/twitter-rest-change-from-api-to-something-meaningful)