# How to customize twitter "via" message in PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

I can't find any mention on how to do this with twitter api. I'd like to do it without buying this commercial software:
http://www.webdesigndev.com/photoshop/how-to-brand-your-tweets-with-your-url-and-why-you-should

I mean not just having my appname but putting any name I want at any time.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's chosen when you create the application for the twitter API: http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

Comment: I mean not just having my appname but putting any name I want at any time.

Comment: Oww, ok. I don't know that. Not sure it's possible.

Comment: @user310291 you can only have it be your app name, and it *doesnt* require ever purchasing any commercial software. You could create many apps with different, and have tweets sent from different apps at different times, but its not particularly worthwhile.

Comment: @yc but that's what the commercial software does. Do they create an app for each client ? Is there a way they can create an app programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this can only be done if your application implements OAuth authentication to Twitter. In the past, non-OAuth apps were able to send a source parameter, but that has been discontinued for any new apps.

From [Twitter's API FAQ](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/api_faq#attributionapplication.)

> If you would like tweets from your
>   application to receive a source
>   parameter, please register an
>   application and implement OAuth
>   authentication. We will automatically
>   include your application as the source
>   for any tweets sent from your
>   application.

Also, check out [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112245/twitter-rest-change-from-api-to-something-meaningful).

Comment: Hello my question is not about how I can show my appname, it's about creating appname for OTHERS.