# Twitter: how to display "via web" when using app

Tags: twitter

I've been reading Twitter doc for a while and there's something that I don't quite understand.

Okay, so basically, when you post something on Twitter, you have the little "16 minutes ago **via**" that indicates where the post comes from. "via web" "via mobile" etc...
I understand that, when you use an application, you can configure it. So you can have "via MyApp".

Now, a friend of mine is using [TweetAdder](http://www.tweetadder.com/) and the via tag displays "via web".

So I've been wondering how they were doing it. I also noted that TweetAdder wasn't using OAuth but asks for nickname/password.

Any hints?

Thanks SO !

Comment: The front page for TweetAdder specifically mentions that they're not using the API. I'm guessing they use web requests behind the scenes to log in to the Twitter UI and post messages as the user (which will be problematic for any paying users of TweetAdder if Twitter ever updates their site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question: [Twitter REST change "from API" to something meaningful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112245/twitter-rest-change-from-api-to-something-meaningful)

They said you **MUST use OAuth** to achieve that. Are you sure they don't use OAuth?

I think they use **XAuth** which is OAuth for trusted applications. With XAuth, an application will send login/password to get an access token. Read more here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth

Comment: Thank you, this should be it. Merci ;)